# Null list returned from Retrofit POJO

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gson, retrofit2

I tried to add dynamic data to Spinner from Server using Retrofit. The data got out. But i got error. Logcat said :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.syaifulhusein.paketku, PID: 31246
>                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

[image]

This my function **initSpinnerKotaAsal** code

```
private void initSpinnerKotaAsal() {
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, "harap tunggu...", true, false);

    mApiService.getProvince(API_KEY).enqueue(new Callback<Rajaongkir>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Rajaongkir> call, Response<Rajaongkir> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                loading.dismiss();
                List<ResultsItem> resultsItems = response.body().getResults();
                List<String> listSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < resultsItems.size(); i++) {
                    listSpinner.add(resultsItems.get(i).getProvince());
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSpinner);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerKotaAsal.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Rajaongkir> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

This my response Object

```
package com.example.syaifulhusein.paketku.model;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Rajaongkir{

@SerializedName("query")
private List<Object> query;

@SerializedName("results")
private List<ResultsItem> results;

@SerializedName("status")
private Status status;

public void setQuery(List<Object> query){
    this.query = query;
}

public List<Object> getQuery(){
    return query;
}

public void setResults(List<ResultsItem> results){
    this.results = results;
}

public List<ResultsItem> getResults(){
    return results;
}

public void setStatus(Status status){
    this.status = status;
}

public Status getStatus(){
    return status;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "Rajaongkir{" + 
        "query = '" + query + '\'' + 
        ",results = '" + results + '\'' + 
        ",status = '" + status + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
}
```

This my **ResultsItem.java**

```
package com.example.syaifulhusein.paketku.model;


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class ResultsItem{

@SerializedName("province")
private String province;

@SerializedName("province_id")
private String provinceId;

public void setProvince(String province){
    this.province = province;
}

public String getProvince(){
    return province;
}

public void setProvinceId(String provinceId){
    this.provinceId = provinceId;
}

public String getProvinceId(){
    return provinceId;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "ResultsItem{" + 
        "province = '" + province + '\'' + 
        ",province_id = '" + provinceId + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem occurs on handling the response on the object. Can you also provide the object?

Comment: @TentenPonce above

Comment: You should check for null and handle it gracefully instead of crashing...

Comment: Try to Log the `response.body()`, and also, add the `ResultsItem` object. So we can check if it is null, means you're not serializing it properly.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use a `List<String>`. You can directly call `adapter.add` with a string object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Anyway, the results are null. They cannot be deserialized. Please show your ResultsItem class

Answer (score 1):

Use `GsonFormate` Plugin to create proper Pojo Model in android Studio.

Comment: Please remove query field and try